# How to add more than one tags for content?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

For example, I want to create two tag, one is "new", the other is "test"，Now tags is "new test"
Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Add tags separated by comma ,

Comment: @Bipin K helpful!!!

Answer (score 1):

You already seem to have 1 field for this content type that is a term reference, whereas the corresponding taxonomy has at least 2 terms (i.e. "test" en "new").

**Solution 1**:

Allow "multiple" or "unlimited" values for the term reference you're already using, which is an option with the field settings of your existing term reference. Which you'll find at `/admin/structure/types/manage/mycontenttype/fields/field_term_ref`, assuming `field_term_ref` is the machine name of your term reference, and `mycontenttype` is the machine name of your content type.

**Solution 2**:

Create an additional term reference field for this content type, and add one of those 2 terms to the new field, and delete it from the term reference field you already have.

**Note**: Which solution to choose depends a bit on your use case:

- If the terms are somehow "related", then solution 1 is what you should use. E.g.: *Target audience* with terms like *visitors, members, editors, administrators*.
- If the terms are not at all "related", then go for solution 2. E.g. *Topic* and *Target audience*.

Comment: There is no need to have two fields to have two different tags.

Comment: I was just adding the 2nd "option" ... And wanted to already do a temporary save ...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but the final and ultimate solution is simply setting the Widget type  to Auto Complete in the widget setting

1. Set up number of values to unlimited in the field setting of the Taxonomy term/ tag of interest.
2. Then Use a comer to separate the tags as you in put them. eg Drupal, modules, etc.